# Using timeslider in QGIS to show census data per year?

Tags: qgis, choropleth, timeslider

I have several shapefiles with the same geographic extend (in my case: Berlin and all its administrative subareas) and statistical (census) attribute data for every subarea displayed trough a choropleth map.

Now I want to show the changing of the figures throughout the given period of time (2007-2015) with QGIS.

Is it possible with several shp or do I have to save all the attribute data for every year into one single shapefile? But if so, how to apply with only one time column (year) but repeating geographical reference (code of subarea) every year then?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS Time Manager is appropriate for this :
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/

You must have a single shapefile with every features. Each features must have a time Start and End attribut. When you play the slider, features will animate according this.

If you want to use this as a web map,  I suggest you Lealfet Timeline (quite the same principle: time Start and End attributs are stored in the geojson in Unix Time Stamp format).